# How Do I Install Ruby Gems on a USB Stick

Tags: ruby, rubygems, usb, installation, portability

How would one install rubygems on a usb stick so that it would work like it would normally, but all files go on the stick? I have no experience at all with rubygems and have no idea of its inner workings, so please, go easy on me! Thanks in advance, ell.

Edit: Basically, so it is entirely portable!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `$GEM_HOME` environment variable to the path where you mounted your usb stick and mine away!

Although for it to be portable you'd have to set `$GEM_HOME` env-variable on other "host" machines as well.

Comment: Note: To do this, add the line `export $GEM_HOME=/usb/stick/gem/installation` to `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile`, and start a new shell.

Comment: @Adrian: Just `export GEM_HOME=…` though (no `$` when setting/exporting variables).

Comment: This works, but it's important to remember that on Windows environments you'd have to configure Windows to constantly assign the same drive label to the USB flash drive such that your gems get installed to the same directory if drive labels got reassigned (or you plugged the USB into a different port)